# Vue 2 how to use libraries without node.js using CDN

Tags: vuejs2, node-modules

I'm making a website with vue2, but I cannot use node.js to install libraries. Now I want to use libraries such as vuetify, but I don't know how to import it in my js files.
Is there a solution? The format of my js file is:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
})
```

When I import it on top of const app, there's an error saying can't be imported outside of the module.

Update: ScreenShot of my code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvyVM.png)

Comment: I'm curious, why can't you use Node? It may be a blocker at some point.

Comment: I've gave them the build file before but it could not be loaded for them.

Comment: and they said they should not npm i anything

Comment: Not sure about the CDN limitation and the fact of not being able to use Node. But you may have some things that do not work well with just a CDN. Also, the performance will be quite bad.

Comment: yes it truly is! and more over, it's because they need some html files just to add in another html files. for e.g I need to make only a data table page and they'll add it in their django project which had pure js ui before

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following code to your HTML file. Remember to wrap your app in v-app though.

Refer to [Use vuetify with CDN](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#usage-with-cdn)

[Working example on codepen](https://codepen.io/milidubey/pen/dyKRyEm?editors=1011)

Could you create a Codepen link with your events.html file? It's easier to debug that way.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="app">
        <v-app>
          <v-main>
            <v-container>Hello world</v-container>
          </v-main>
        </v-app>
      </div>
    
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
      <script>
        new Vue({
          el: '#app',
          vuetify: new Vuetify(),
        })
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I did it by none of the tags works for me. it says unknown html tag

Comment: Could you post your code and screenshot of the error?

Comment: I'll add screenshot in few seconds

Comment: Hi Sanaz, that's just Webstorm complaining, you can probably ignore it. Did you try adding vuetify tags like v-card, v-btn etc? I've created a codepen link for you. It should work. Could you create a codepen for events.html?

Comment: I'll try adding a codepen link. well, I've tried that too but nothing would display. let me make a codepen and I'll inform you